# Facebook In-line Video Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, embed, jwplayer6

On my website, I use JWPlayer to play video content. I would love to embed a player hosted on my website into a Facebook post that plays in the post and not link to another website. When I use JWPlayer's embed wizard on their website, it creates a page on their server with the player and gives some iframe code that I can paste into Facebook. This works completely fine. However, I really need to be able to make an automated process that creates embed pages on my own site independent of JWPlayer's website.

I took the source code and modified it to fit my website, but unfortunately Facebook does not allow it to play inline. It shows the splash image, title, and description but does not have a play button. When I click the image, it takes me to my website rather than playing the video within the post.

When researching the issue on Facebook's dev reference, I saw that you need a secure URL. My website has an SSL certificate. However, it does not have an EV certificate like JWPlayer's website. Could this be the issue? I don't want to spend the money on it unless I know it will work.

Here is my html heading if it helps at all. And I am using JWPlayer 7. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
<head prefix="og:http://ogp.me/ns#">
        <title>HTTP test video</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.examplewebsite.com/embed/player.html">
        <meta property="og:title" content="HTTPS test video">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.examplewebsite.com/embed/og_image.jpg">
        <meta property="og:description" content="This is a test.">
        <meta property="og:type" content="video">
        <meta property="og:video:url" content="https://examplewebsite.com/embed/jwplayer.flash.swf">
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://examplewebsite.com/embed/jwplayer.flash.swf">
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
        <meta property="og:video:width" content="480">
        <meta property="og:video:height" content="270">
    </head>
```

Comment: Check your OG meta tags using the debug tool, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't help me much... I just had to delete stuff and add it back till it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the problem. For some reason, the og:url tag was messing the whole thing up. I removed that tag and everything works fine as far as displaying inline. I do not know why that fixes it, but it works. However, I believe JWPlayer 6 and 7 don't support Facebook embed... But that is a different issue.